# .NET Core .dll cannot find or open the symbol file

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm currently doing a small CLI app in .NET Core, working with VSCode. I'm getting a really strange message however, when i run debugging:

> Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/System.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
>   Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
>   Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/System.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
>   Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/System.Collections.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
>   Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/System.Console.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
>   Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/1.1.0/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.

That said, the code runs just fine, I am just scratching my head, wondering what in the world this means then, because to me it seems like some environment variables must be wrong, as it looks like the right dll's can't be found. Yet, at the same time, it says: "loaded " so it's not the DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just means that the debugger couldn't find debugging information for the listed libraries. This should not cause any issues for you (as long as you don't need to step into those libraries, which you almost never do).

Comment: Is it possible to disable these warnings for .net core libraries like `System.Collections.dll` and others?